# Android: different layout in differnet devices

Tags: android, android-layout, device

I created an Android application. I tried this on differnet device and I have different layout in any Activity of my app. My Project Build Target is 2.3.3.
The two devices I used are:

1. Samsung Galaxy S2 - Android 2.3.6
2. HTC Desire - Android 2.3.5

For example the main Activity produces this layout in my Samsung:

[image]

and this in my HTC:

[image]

Why the two layout are so different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because before Google introduced holo in Ice Cream Sandwich, manufacturers had a free hand in deciding how their devices' version of Android would look. Because of this, they could theme it to whatever they want.

I'm pretty sure that your app hasn't defined its own theme, and this is why you're getting such radically different looks on different devices.

To fix it, simply create your own theme and apply it to your activities.

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)  document can help you with styling your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) with the Holo theme and Action Bar on older android versions (under 3.0).